# Enqueuing latest version of jQuery into a child theme returns a blank screen

Tags: functions, jquery, child-theme, twitter-bootstrap, parent-theme

Wordpress beginner here. I created a child theme and I'm trying to enqueue Bootstrap 4 inside the functions.php file. From my understanding, if I want to enqueue Bootstrap properly I need to enqueue the latest version of jQuery first. I believe the parent theme is running an older version of jQuery because I see jQueryUI files like `core.min.js?ver=1.11.4` in `wp-includes/js/jquery/ui`, so I use `wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );` then enqueue the latest version of jQuery. My functions.php code is below

```
<?php

function kloe_freelance_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kloe_freelance_enqueue_styles' );

function kloe_freelance_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js');

// popper.js is enqueued because Bootstrap 4 requires it to work. 

wp_enqueue_script('popper_js','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kloe_freelance_enqueue_scripts');

?>
```

When I run my website, I get a blank screen. According to the console, I'm getting these errors.

[image]

Why am I getting a blank screen? I think I'm getting the blank screen because the latest version of jQuery is incompatible with the parent theme's js files (`modules.min.js, like.min.js`), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like some compatability issues are present.  There is an answer to a very similar situation on stack exchange here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738732/jquery-3-0-url-indexof-error